# Concatenate and change extension

Tags: linux, shell, unix

I'm trying to concatenate files 1.txt and 2.txt, and several html files. I'm also trying to save them as `.php` after concatenation after. I've tried to do as follows, but it doesn't work.

Step 1:

```
sudo find . -name "*.html" -type f -exec ./code.sh {} \;
```

Code.sh

```
cat 1.txt $1 2.txt > mv $1 `echo $1 | sed 's/\.html/.php/'`;
```

Any ideas how to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you're trying to write to a file called `mv` along with some other parameters.

I think what you mean for code.sh is:

```
cat 1.txt $1 2.txt > $(echo $1 | sed 's/\.html/.php/')
```

Comment: No works :(
`sed: -e expresión #1, carácter 13: orden `s' sin terminar
./code.sh: 1: ./code.sh: cannot create : Directory nonexistent
sed: -e expresión #1, carácter 13: orden `s' sin terminar
./code.sh: 1: ./code.sh: cannot create : Directory nonexistent
`

Comment: @user3680708 - Whoops, missed a frontslash at the end.

Answer (score 0):

how about

```
file=$1
filephp=${file%html}php

cat 1.txt $file 2.txt > $filephp
```

Comment: Explaining that this uses Parameter Expansion with [Substring removal](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe#substring_removal) will make this so much more understandable to the general audience.